# How to extract sql scripts from classic database dump oracle (exp)?

Tags: sql, oracle, import, dump

Am trying to extract the sql script from classic database dump (not data pump), because I need to know some information in insert statements!

Could I perform that with `imp`?

How could I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "SQL script".  If you mean the DDL for the tables, you can get that.  If you want to convert a dump file to a series of `insert` statements, you're probably not going to be able to do that easily.  I believe there are third party tools that might be able to do that but it's generally easier to import the file into an Oracle database and then generate the `insert` statements from there.

Comment: @JustinCave The idea is that I want to extract the statements without having the user  in my DB. I need to know some information before importing the dump!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the statements"?  A dump file contains DDL statements.  It does not contain DML statements.  There are no `insert` statements to extract.  There are, as I said, third party tools that can read the data from a dump file and generate an `insert` statement from that.  But those tools are unlikely to be free and it's generally easier to just import the dump file into an Oracle database first even if you're creating an instance just for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the documentation.  See the [SHOW parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#SUTIL1729).

> SHOW
>
> Default: n
>
> When SHOW=y, the contents of the export dump file are listed to the
> display and not imported. The SQL statements contained in the export
> are displayed in the order in which Import will execute them.
>
> The SHOW parameter can be used only with the FULL=y, FROMUSER, TOUSER,
> or TABLES parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but show does not extract all statements like insert statements

Comment: DevOps -  Ah.  It's been quite a while since I last used it, and the docs didn't mention any limitations on _what_ is extracted.